# Flutter Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter

I am getting null value from api with variable of storeUserID, in this variable i stored user id at the time of register but when i run app it shows null value.
But when i manully type id like this **https://aeliya.000webhostapp.com/demo.php?id=106764933065187174744** is shows me data.

```
//get users details
  Future<GetUserData> getUserDetail() async {
    var url = "https://aeliya.000webhostapp.com/demo.php?id=$storeUserID";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(data);
      print(storeUserID);
      //print(data[0]['isAdmin']);
      return GetUserData.fromJson(data);
    } else {
      return GetUserData.fromJson(data);
    }
  }
```

at the same time i am getting following error.

> E/flutter (13406): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of
> 'index' E/flutter (13406): #0      new GetUserData.fromJson
> (package:mahuva_azadari/Models/GetUserData.dart:19:17) E/flutter
> (13406): #1      _AdminReqState.getUserDetail
> (package:mahuva_azadari/Screens/Admin%20Request.dart:352:26) E/flutter
> (13406):

Following is my response:

```
 [{"name":"Taki Rajani","email":"mohammadtaki.rajani@gmail.com","isAdmin":"0","description":"testing "}]
```

**GetUserData**

```
/// name : "Taki Rajani"
/// email : "mohammadtaki.rajani@gmail.com"
/// isAdmin : "0"
/// description : "testing "

class GetUserData {
  GetUserData({
      String? name, 
      String? email, 
      String? isAdmin, 
      String? description,}){
    _name = name;
    _email = email;
    _isAdmin = isAdmin;
    _description = description;
}

  GetUserData.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    _name = json['name'];
    _email = json['email'];
    _isAdmin = json['isAdmin'];
    _description = json['description'];
  }
  String? _name;
  String? _email;
  String? _isAdmin;
  String? _description;
GetUserData copyWith({  String? name,
  String? email,
  String? isAdmin,
  String? description,
}) => GetUserData(  name: name ?? _name,
  email: email ?? _email,
  isAdmin: isAdmin ?? _isAdmin,
  description: description ?? _description,
);
  String? get name => _name;
  String? get email => _email;
  String? get isAdmin => _isAdmin;
  String? get description => _description;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['name'] = _name;
    map['email'] = _email;
    map['isAdmin'] = _isAdmin;
    map['description'] = _description;
    return map;
  }

}
```

Comment: could you please share GetUserData class file.

Comment: I edited my answer with GetUserData class code

Answer (score 0):

so I see the error in
Models/GetUserData.dart
I think in your model
"isAdmin":"0" you save it as int but it is returning from the api as String

Comment: ok, can i change this in my GetUserData file??

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  Future<GetUserData> getUserDetail() async {
    var url = "https://aeliya.000webhostapp.com/demo.php?id=$storeUserID";
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(data);
      print(storeUserID);
      //print(data[0]['isAdmin']);
      return GetUserData.fromJson(data[0]); <--- made this change
    } else {
      return GetUserData.fromJson(data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: not working, i changed variable in data base int to text but same error

Comment: I edited my message please try this.